# How to pass a date to command line?

Tags: go

Go has a few predefined types in its [flag](https://pkg.go.dev/flag) package. How would I pass a date?

I have mimicked [the URL parsing example](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#example-Value) but it looks a bit verbose and I am missing smth.

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const dateLayout = "2006-01-02"

type DateValue struct {
    Date *time.Time
}

func (v DateValue) String() string {
    if v.Date != nil {
        return v.Date.Format(dateLayout)
    }
    return ""
}

func (v DateValue) Set(str string) error {
    if t, err := time.Parse(dateLayout, str); err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        *v.Date = t
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var d = &time.Time{}

    flag.Var(&DateValue{d}, "date", "Date part of ISO")
    flag.Parse([]string{"--date", "2022-08-08"})
    fmt.Printf(`{date: %q}`, d)
}
```

Alas, this fails with an error. You can see it at the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/scWNtnRsBVU)

> ./prog.go:35:13: too many arguments in call to flag.Parse
>
> have ([]string)
>
> want ()

Comment: `flag.Parse()` does not take any arguments. It parses the arguments passed in the CLI. Use `flag.NewFlagSet()` and its `FlagSet.Parse()` method to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parse](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Parse) parses the command-line flags from `os.Args[1:]` and needs to be called after the  top level flags are defined. To build sub-commands e.g. `prog --date <date-val>`, use a `Flagset`.

You can notice from the method signature, that it does [not take any arguments](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Parse), which is the reason for your immediate error on the argument mismatch ([pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/flag) is your friend)

With your code as shown, create a default [Flagset](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#NewFlagSet) and assign new flags and associated values

```golang
func main() {
    var d = &time.Time{}
    fs := flag.NewFlagSet("DateValue", flag.ExitOnError)
    
    fs.Var(&DateValue{d}, "date", "Date part of ISO")
    fs.Parse([]string{"--date", "2022-08-08"})

    fmt.Printf(`{date: %q}`, d)
}
```

[go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/y7-ov2vjHwN)